# Natural Number Generator

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

Motivated with [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/605253) question I formulated following question :

Does $\lfloor \sqrt{p} \rfloor$ generate all natural numbers where $p$ is a prime number of the form $4k+3$ ?

I wrote Maxima implementation of this generator :

```
P:[];
N:[];
p:3;
while p<20000 do
(if (mod(p,4)=3) then P:append(P,[p]),
p:next_prime(p))$
for i from 1 thru length(P) do
(m:floor(sqrt(P[i])),
if (not member(m,N)) then N:append(N,[m]))$
N;
```

You can run this code [here](http://maxima-online.org/?inc=r-61449976) .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\lfloor \sqrt{p}\rfloor = n$ [if and only if](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions)
$$n\le \sqrt{p}<n+1$$
if and only if 
$$n^2\le p<(n+1)^2$$
OP demands a prime (of a particular type, no less) between each pair of consecutive squares.  This is known as [Legendre's conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre%27s_conjecture) and is open, even without the $4k+3$ restriction.